# store data from two tables into one php array

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to store all data from the tables listed in $tables into an array, then encode it as json. However, only the last entry from orderInfo is being stored. How do I fix this? I think mysqli_num_rows behaves differently when working with data from a single table

```
$tables = array('userInfo', 'orderInfo');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tables); $i++) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$tables[$i]}`;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $data = array();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              $data[$tables[$i]] = $row;
          }
        }
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Move empty array `$data` before for loops

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Using `die` like this is pretty pathological. Why not `echo` and then exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move empty array `$data` before for loops, because every loops `$data` will reset until last entry

also change `$data[$tables[$i]]` in while loop to `$data[$tables[$i]][]`

```
<?php

$data = array();
$tables = array('userInfo', 'orderInfo');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tables); $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$tables[$i]}`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $data[$tables[$i]][] = $row;
      }
    }
}
die(json_encode($data));
```

better way, you dont need count `$table`

because you can loop array using `foreach`

```
<?php

$data = array();
$tables = array('userInfo', 'orderInfo');
foreach ($tables as $tbl) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$tbl}`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $data[$tbl][] = $row;
      }
    }
}
die(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's been mentioned, you'll need to move $data out of the for loop, additionally you should be able to nix the if statement before the while. It's redundant as the while shouldn't run anyway if there are no rows:

```
$data = [];
$tables = array('userInfo', 'orderInfo');
foreach($tables as $tableName){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$tableName}`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[$tableName] = $row;
    }
}
die(json_encode($data));
```